# How do I unmap the forward and back keys on my Lenovo laptop?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keymap

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad x200s. how do I unmap the forward and backward keys?

I want something like..

> xmodmap -e 'keycode 166=NOOP'

Or some way to ignore the `XF86Back` keysym.

Answer (score 2):

Damn, I was close...

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 166='
xmodmap -e 'keycode 167='
```